# Cycles my image is black and blue, but EEVEE in normal color

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

When I render in Cycles my image is black and blue, but if I render EEVEE in the color is normal. What is the reason?

Output RGB. I use Blender3.0

[image: cycles render]

[image: Eevee render]

[image: shader editor rice and output RGB]

Comment: It's just a viewport shading,cycle always looks like this,the purpose is to save resources.When you really export it, it will looks ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the displayed image is a finished render image. I wonder if it's due to the setting? Because before I used this model at blender 2.9 and no problem.

Comment: pls upload your file.

Comment: I'm sorry for sending files late. this is my file Thank you very much for your help. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ho7IJ9nvOEym-5La49ZukF8cQW-if1b2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- click Denoise
- reduce the number of Transmission and Subsurface in your Principle BSDF
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for you help. I forgot it and I 'm going to have to modify the New Shader editor.